# convert outlook msg to html using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I'm pretty new to vbscript and I'm just writing a simple script that converts an msg file to html. So far I have:

```
Dim objshell,BaseName,outlookapp,emailPath
Set objshell= CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set email = outlookapp.CreateItemFromTemplate(emailPath)

BaseName = objshell.GetBaseName(emailPath)
emailPath = "C:\Users\makkerman\Desktop\email folder\test.msg"

email.saveas objshell.GetParentFolderName(emailPath) & BaseName & ".html", olFormatHTML

outlookapp.Quit
```

However, I get no output (and no errors). Can someone enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

Side note: how would I write this so that my current instance of Outlook doesn't close when I run the script as it currently does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML (2), but you need OlSaveAsType.olHTML (5).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I tried that, but then I get an error saying, "Object required: 'OlSaveAsType'". I thought the email variable would've been an object already?

Comment: Specify just olHTML . Or 5.

Comment: Sorry, still no output but changing 5 got rid of the error at least :). I'll continue to research. Thx

Comment: Sorry, I made a silly mistake: forgot to put a "\" between objshell.GetParentFolderName(emailPath) and BaseName in the saveas path. Thanks for your help!